# Why did my MacBook Pro burn 15% of battery while sleeping?

Tags: macos, laptop, battery, sleep, macbook

SUMMARY

My MacBook Pro has not been sleeping E.g. it is still warm after being closed in my bag for hours. Here is some info from the pmset log the last time this happened. Key lines are here:

Closed the lid here:

```
2019-05-22 21:47:04 -0700 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Clamshell Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using Batt (Charge:70%) 9808 secs
```

... Then after I opened it, it reported this:

```
2019-05-23 07:59:52 -0700 DarkWake              DarkWake from Standby [CDN] due to EC.DarkPME ARPT/HID Activity: Using BATT (Charge:55%) 2 secs
```

I have tried the following:

- Checking Activity Monitor for anything preventing sleep, nothing is.

The log activity seems a bit strange, it reports 70% battery seconds before it changes to 55%, so maybe something else is wrong too.

FULL RESULTS OF `pmset -g log`

```
Time stamp                Domain                Message                                                                     Duration    Delay     
==========                ======                =======                                                                     ========    =====     
UUID: EDA2A8FD-4588-409D-9336-2CF55A415196
2019-05-22 21:47:04 -0700 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Clamshell Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using Batt (Charge:70%) 9808 secs 
2019-05-22 21:47:18 -0700 Assertions            PID 87(apsd) Released ApplePushServiceTask "com.apple.apsd-connectionestablish-push.apple.com" 00:00:20  id:0x0xb0000830e [System: PrevIdle DeclUser IntPrevDisp kDisp]          
2019-05-22 21:47:32 -0700 Wake Requests         [*proc=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff inDelta=43232]           
2019-05-22 21:47:32 -0700 PM Client Acks        Delays to Sleep notifications: [mDNSResponder is slow(5017 ms)] [com.apple.apsd timed out(28001 ms)]           
2019-05-23 00:30:31 -0700 Kernel Client Acks    Delays to Sleep notifications: [AppleIntelFramebuffer driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(1743 ms)] [SymDaemon timed out(30000 ms)] [powerd is slow(28003 ms)] [UPSB driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(937 ms)] [UPSB driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(938 ms)] [AppleHPMIECS driver is slow(msg: WillChangeState to 2)(1055 ms)] [AppleHPMIECS driver is slow(msg: WillChangeState to 2)(1055 ms)]           
2019-05-23 00:30:31 -0700 Assertions            PID 187(mDNSResponder) Created MaintenanceWake "mDNSResponder:maintenance" 00:00:00  id:0x0xd00008315 [System: PrevIdle DeclUser IntPrevDisp kDisp]          
2019-05-23 00:30:31 -0700 Assertions            PID 2111(cloudphotosd) Released BackgroundTask "com.apple.cloudphotosd.darkwake.sync" 02:43:56  id:0x0xb00008301 [System: PrevIdle DeclUser IntPrevDisp kDisp]          
2019-05-23 00:30:31 -0700 Notification          Next immediate inactivity window start:'2019-05-23 00:30:00 -0700' end:'2019-05-23 09:00:00 -0700'            
2019-05-23 00:30:31 -0700 Assertions            PID 187(mDNSResponder) Released MaintenanceWake "mDNSResponder:maintenance" 00:00:00  id:0x0xd00008315 [System: PrevIdle DeclUser IntPrevDisp kDisp]          
2019-05-23 00:30:32 -0700 DarkWake              DarkWake from Normal Sleep [CDN] due to EC.SleepTimer/SleepTimer: Using BATT (Charge:70%) 42 secs   
2019-05-23 00:30:32 -0700 HibernateStats        hibmode=3 standbydelay=10800                                                          146           
2019-05-23 00:30:32 -0700 WakeTime              WakeTime: 2.276 sec                                                                   
2019-05-23 00:30:32 -0700 Kernel Client Acks    Delays to Wake notifications: [AirPort_BrcmNIC driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(315 ms)] [UPSB driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(542 ms)] [UPSB driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(542 ms)] [AMDFramebufferVIB driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(315 ms)]           
2019-05-23 00:30:32 -0700 Assertions            PID 91(timed) Released NoIdleSleepAssertion "com.apple.timed.ntp" 02:43:26  id:0x0x100008310 [System: DeclUser IntPrevDisp IPushSrvc kCPU kDisp]          
2019-05-23 00:30:44 -0700 Assertions            PID 87(apsd) Released ApplePushServiceTask "com.apple.apsd-connectionestablish-push.apple.com" 02:43:26  id:0x0xb00008313 [System: PrevIdle DeclUser IntPrevDisp IPushSrvc kCPU kDisp]          
2019-05-23 00:30:52 -0700 Assertions            PID 87(apsd) Released InteractivePushServiceTask "com.apple.apsd-wakeconnection-push.apple.com" 00:00:19  id:0x0x120000831a [System: PrevIdle DeclUser IntPrevDisp IPushSrvc kCPU kDisp]          
2019-05-23 00:31:03 -0700 Assertions            PID 2838(diskmanagementd) Released PreventUserIdleSystemSleep "com.apple.diskmanagementd" 00:00:15  id:0x0x100008320 [System: PrevIdle DeclUser IntPrevDisp IPushSrvc kCPU kDisp]          
2019-05-23 00:31:05 -0700 Assertions            PID 91(timed) Released NoIdleSleepAssertion "com.apple.timed.ntp" 00:00:30  id:0x0x10000831b [System: DeclUser IntPrevDisp IPushSrvc kCPU kDisp]          
2019-05-23 00:31:14 -0700 Assertions            PID 87(apsd) Released InteractivePushServiceTask "com.apple.apsd-connectionestablish-push.apple.com" 00:00:30  id:0x0x120000831d [System: PrevIdle DeclUser IntPrevDisp kDisp]          
2019-05-23 00:31:14 -0700 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using Batt (Charge:70%) 26918 secs
2019-05-23 00:31:14 -0700 Wake Requests         [*proc=powerd request=AdaptiveWake inDelta=26925] [proc=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff inDelta=33410]           
2019-05-23 07:59:51 -0700 Assertions            PID 61(powerd) TimedOut InternalPreventDisplaySleep "com.apple.powermanagement.delayDisplayOff" 10:13:30  id:0x0x1000008185 [System: PrevIdle DeclUser IntPrevDisp kDisp]          
2019-05-23 07:59:51 -0700 Assertions            Summary- [System: PrevIdle DeclUser kDisp] Using Batt(Charge: 70)          
2019-05-23 07:59:51 -0700 Kernel Client Acks    Delays to Sleep notifications: [UPSB driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(939 ms)] [UPSB driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(939 ms)] [AppleHPMIECS driver is slow(msg: WillChangeState to 2)(1056 ms)] [AppleHPMIECS driver is slow(msg: WillChangeState to 2)(1056 ms)] [AirPort_BrcmNIC driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(312 ms)]           
2019-05-23 07:59:51 -0700 Assertions            PID 61(powerd) Created InternalPreventSleep "Holding in darkwake for up to 30 seconds to update inactivity prediction" 00:00:00  id:0x0xd00008326 [System: PrevIdle DeclUser SRPrevSleep kCPU kDisp]          
2019-05-23 07:59:51 -0700 Assertions            PID 187(mDNSResponder) Created MaintenanceWake "mDNSResponder:maintenance" 00:00:00  id:0x0xd00008329 [System: PrevIdle DeclUser SRPrevSleep kCPU kDisp]          
2019-05-23 07:59:51 -0700 Notification          Next largest inactivity window start:'2019-05-23 20:15:00 -0700' end:'2019-05-24 09:00:00 -0700'              
2019-05-23 07:59:51 -0700 Assertions            PID 61(powerd) Released InternalPreventSleep "Holding in darkwake for up to 30 seconds to update inactivity prediction" 00:00:00  id:0x0xd00008326 [System: PrevIdle DeclUser kDisp]          
2019-05-23 07:59:51 -0700 Assertions            PID 113(hidd) TurnedOn UserIsActive "com.apple.iohideventsystem.queue.tickle.4294970777.3" 00:00:00  id:0x0x900008212 [System: PrevIdle DeclUser kDisp]          
2019-05-23 07:59:51 -0700 Assertions            PID 113(hidd) TurnedOn UserIsActive "com.apple.iohideventsystem.queue.tickle.4294970777.3" 00:00:00  id:0x0x900008212 [System: PrevIdle DeclUser kDisp]          
2019-05-23 07:59:52 -0700 Assertions            PID 61(powerd) Created InternalPreventSleep "PM configd - Wait for Device enumeration" 00:00:00  id:0x0xd0000832a [System: PrevIdle DeclUser kDisp]          
2019-05-23 07:59:52 -0700 DarkWake              DarkWake from Standby [CDN] due to EC.DarkPME ARPT/HID Activity: Using BATT (Charge:55%) 2 secs    
2019-05-23 07:59:52 -0700 WakeDetails           DriverReason:ARPT - DriverDetails:                                         
DriverReason:WiFi.ScanOffload-Group key handshake timeout - DriverDetails: 
2019-05-23 07:59:52 -0700 HibernateStats        hibmode=3 standbydelay=10800                                                          rd=539 ms     
2019-05-23 07:59:52 -0700 WakeTime              WakeTime: 4.728 sec                                                                   
2019-05-23 07:59:52 -0700 Kernel Client Acks    Delays to Wake notifications: [UPSB driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(540 ms)] [UPSB driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(540 ms)] [AMDFramebufferVIB driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(319 ms)]           
2019-05-23 07:59:53 -0700 Assertions            PID 187(mDNSResponder) Released MaintenanceWake "mDNSResponder:maintenance" 00:00:01  id:0x0xd00008329 [System: PrevIdle DeclUser SRPrevSleep kCPU kDisp]          
2019-05-23 07:59:53 -0700 Assertions            Kernel Idle sleep preventers: IODisplayWrangler          
2019-05-23 07:59:53 -0700 Notification          Display is turned on                                                                  
2019-05-23 07:59:54 -0700 Wake                  DarkWake to FullWake from Standby [CDNVA] due to HID Activity: Using BATT (Charge:55%)           
2019-05-23 07:59:54 -0700 WakeDetails           DriverReason:ARPT - DriverDetails:                                         
DriverReason:WiFi.ScanOffload-Group key handshake timeout - DriverDetails: 
2019-05-23 07:59:54 -0700 HibernateStats        hibmode=3 standbydelay=10800                                                          rd=539 ms     
2019-05-23 07:59:54 -0700 WakeTime              WakeTime: 0.462 sec                                                                   
2019-05-23 07:59:54 -0700 Kernel Client Acks    Delays to Wake notifications: [AppleHDADriver driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(432 ms)]           
2019-05-23 08:00:08 -0700 Assertions            PID 61(powerd) Released InternalPreventSleep "PM configd - Wait for Device enumeration" 00:00:16  id:0x0xd0000832a [System: DeclUser IPushSrvc kCPU kDisp]          
Total Sleep/Wakes since boot at 2019-05-22 21:06:36 -0700 :2
2019-05-23 08:00:43 -0700 : Showing all currently held IOKit power assertions
Assertion status system-wide:
   BackgroundTask                 0
   ApplePushServiceTask           0
   UserIsActive                   1
   PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep    0
   InteractivePushServiceTask     1
   PreventSystemSleep             0
   ExternalMedia                  0
   PreventUserIdleSystemSleep     1
   NetworkClientActive            0
Listed by owning process:
   pid 91(timed): [0x00000a080001835b] 00:00:03 NoIdleSleepAssertion named: "com.apple.timed.ntp" 
    Timeout will fire in 107 secs Action=TimeoutActionTurnOff
   pid 113(hidd): [0x000004c500098212] 00:00:01 UserIsActive named: "com.apple.iohideventsystem.queue.tickle.4294970661.3" 
    Timeout will fire in 119 secs Action=TimeoutActionRelease
   pid 2111(cloudphotosd): [0x000009db000b833d] 00:00:48 BackgroundTask named: "com.apple.cloudphotosd.darkwake.sync" 
    Details: cloudphotosd darkwake power assertion for initial and large iCPL downloads/uploads
    Timeout will fire in 1752 secs Action=TimeoutActionTurnOff
   pid 473(UserEventAgent): [0x000009eb000b8353] 00:00:32 BackgroundTask named: "com.apple.AddressBook.ScheduledSync" 
    Created for PID: 3022. 
   pid 87(apsd): [0x000009f900128357] 00:00:18 InteractivePushServiceTask named: "com.apple.apsd-connectionestablish-push.apple.com" 
    Timeout will fire in 162 secs Action=TimeoutActionTurnOff
   pid 3022(AddressBookSourceSync): [0x000009eb00018352] 00:00:32 PreventUserIdleSystemSleep named: "Address Book Source Sync" 
    Timeout will fire in 1767 secs Action=TimeoutActionTurnOff
   pid 254(mds_stores): [0x00000a0b000b835c] 00:00:01 BackgroundTask named: "com.apple.metadata.mds_stores.power" 
Kernel Assertions: 0x8=BT-HID
   id=504  level=255 0x8=BT-HID mod=12/31/69, 4:00 PM description=com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver owner=IOBluetoothHIDDriver
Idle sleep preventers: IODisplayWrangler
```

My Mac:

- Model Name:  MacBook Pro
- Model Identifier:    MacBookPro14,3
- Processor Name:  Intel Core i7
- Processor Speed: 3.1 GHz
- Number of Processors:    1
- Total Number of Cores:   4
- L2 Cache (per Core): 256 KB
- L3 Cache:    8 MB
- Memory:  16 GB
- Boot ROM Version:    190.0.0.0.0
- SMC Version (system):    2.45f0

Answer (score 2):

Check in Settings / Energy Saver that Power Nap is not enabled on battery. I disable it even when plugged in.
Also check this answer related to Address Book Sync: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/237552/334268

**The long story**

It seems your mac woke once at 00:30 from light sleep for almost a minute, then at 07:59 from standby when you opened the lid.
It also seems it would have woken at 09:00 again if you hadn't opened it before that happened:

```
2019-05-23 00:30:31 -0700 Notification          Next immediate inactivity window start:'2019-05-23 00:30:00 -0700' end:'2019-05-23 09:00:00 -0700'
```

By default macs are configured to stay in light sleep for 3 or 4 hours. During this time they can perform background tasks like syncing things.
The interesting section of your log starts at `Assertion status system-wide:`.

It seems you had a cloud photo sync that took less than a minute if my interpretation is correct: `00:00:48 BackgroundTask named: "com.apple.cloudphotosd.darkwake.sync"`, corresponding to this entry:

```
2019-05-23 00:30:31 -0700 Assertions            PID 2111(cloudphotosd) Released BackgroundTask "com.apple.cloudphotosd.darkwake.sync" 02:43:56  id:0x0xb00008301 [System: PrevIdle DeclUser IntPrevDisp kDisp]
```

And an address book sync: `00:00:32 BackgroundTask named: "com.apple.AddressBook.ScheduledSync`.
This last one is marked as `PreventUserIdleSystemSleep` so it might be the culprit. Or maybe both syncs account for 15%.
The report of 70% just before 55% is probably a glitch before the system actually polled the battery for the current value. I saw this happen even in the user interface when opening the lid. Before logging in the battery would show the last logged value, after logging in it would show the real one.